# weird R issue - values in a variable get missing after the if loop

Tags: r, loops, variables, if-statement

I have a rather odd problem - after I compute some dates (stored in variable 'datumi'), and if I run it like in the first case below, I get an error saying that the last if loop misses value (Error in if ({ : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed).

dataframe d (which i would rather upload as a .csv file, but I can't see that option):

```
d = 
1  2012-09-16  0.84 19.625243     FALSE   19.62524
2  2012-09-17  0.84 33.327431     FALSE   52.95267
3  2012-09-18  0.84 62.887769     FALSE  115.84044
4  2012-09-19  0.84 28.452394     FALSE  144.29284
5  2012-09-20  0.84 70.913258     FALSE  215.20610
6  2012-09-21  0.84 40.573884     FALSE  255.77998
7  2012-09-22  0.84 66.525374      TRUE  322.30535
8  2012-09-27  0.97 54.060930      TRUE  376.36628
9  2012-12-11  0.94 59.708620      TRUE  436.07490
10 2013-02-18  0.84 61.645767     FALSE  497.72067
11 2013-02-19  0.84 24.086509      TRUE  521.80718
12 2013-02-27  0.94 58.148436     FALSE  579.95562
13 2013-02-28  0.94  6.884530     FALSE  586.84015
14 2013-03-01  0.94 18.269344     FALSE  605.10949
15 2013-03-03  0.94 24.968575     FALSE  630.07807
16 2013-03-04  0.94 29.888434     FALSE  659.96650
17 2013-03-05  0.94 70.158147     FALSE  730.12465
18 2013-03-06  0.94 67.772256     FALSE  797.89690
19 2013-03-07  0.94 74.875140     FALSE  872.77204
20 2013-03-08  0.94 10.682086     FALSE  883.45413
21 2013-03-10  0.94 83.325472     FALSE  966.77960
22 2013-03-11  0.94 61.428804     FALSE 1028.20840
23 2013-03-12  0.94 90.050368     FALSE 1118.25877
24 2013-03-13  0.94 57.943451     FALSE 1176.20222
25 2013-03-14  0.94 29.740228     FALSE 1205.94245
26 2013-03-15  0.94  6.786190     FALSE 1212.72864
27 2013-03-17  0.94 64.275445     FALSE 1277.00409
28 2013-03-18  0.94 14.502550     FALSE 1291.50664
29 2013-03-19  0.94 60.892779     FALSE 1352.39942
30 2013-03-20  0.94 31.152046     FALSE 1383.55146
31 2013-03-21  0.94 40.834755     FALSE 1424.38622
32 2013-03-22  0.94 13.317670     FALSE 1437.70389
33 2013-03-24  0.94 54.218275     FALSE 1491.92216
34 2013-03-25  0.94 10.910257     FALSE 1502.83242
35 2013-03-26  0.94  5.688037     FALSE 1508.52046
36 2013-03-27  0.94 27.859595     FALSE 1536.38005
37 2013-03-28  0.94 32.144926     FALSE 1568.52498
38 2013-03-29  0.94 42.197229      TRUE 1610.72221
39 2013-04-01  0.84  1.973316     FALSE 1612.69552
40 2013-04-02  0.84 70.191520     FALSE 1682.88704
41 2013-04-03  0.84 47.700082     FALSE 1730.58712
42 2013-04-04  0.84 65.108000     FALSE 1795.69512
43 2013-04-05  0.84 65.686734     FALSE 1861.38186
44 2013-04-07  0.84 82.046046     FALSE 1943.42790
45 2013-04-08  0.84 28.383566     FALSE 1971.81147
46 2013-04-09  0.84  8.957643     FALSE 1980.76911
47 2013-04-10  0.84 56.305904     FALSE 2037.07502
48 2013-04-11  0.84 32.909041     FALSE 2069.98406
49 2013-04-12  0.84 81.166025     FALSE 2151.15008
50 2013-04-14  0.84 58.212950     FALSE 2209.36303
```

The code:

```
l = 2
spr <- matrix(,,5)
datumi <- c()
datumi[1] <- as.character(as.Date("2012-07-24", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
spr[1,2] <- 0
spr[1,5] <- 0
for(j in 1:nrow(d)){
    if(d[j,4] == TRUE){
        spr <- rbind(spr,NA)
        datumi[l] <- if(j < nrow(d)){
            as.character(as.Date(d[{j+1},1], format = "%Y-%m-%d"))  
            } else {
            as.character(as.Date("2014-01-15", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
            }
        spr[l,1] <- difftime(datumi[l],datumi[l-1],units="days")  
        if(spr[l,1] == 0){
            spr[l,1] <- 1
        }
        spr[l,2] <- d[j,5] - spr[{l-1},5]  
        spr[l,3] <- spr[l,2] / spr[l,1]  
        spr[l,4] <- as.numeric(as.character(d[j,2]))  
        spr[l,5] <- d[j,5]
        l = l+1
    } 

datumi <- as.Date(datumi)

days <- seq(from=as.Date("2012-07-24"), to=as.Date("2014-01-15"),by='days')


freq <- c()
  for(j in i:length(days)){
    for(k in 2:length(datumi)){
        if({datumi[k-1] <= days[j]} && {days[j] < datumi[k]}){
            freq[j] <- spr[k,3]
        }
    }
}
```

The result now is the aformentioned error:

(Error in if ({ : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed)

Which happens because 'datumi' looks like that:

> datumi
>   [1] "2012-07-24"

instead of like that, which is the correct way:

> datumi
>   [1] "2012-07-24" "2013-10-03" "2013-12-13" "2013-12-13" "2013-12-14" "2013-12-15" "2014-01-15"

But an interesting thing happens when I run both parts of the code seperately:

```
l = 2
spr <- matrix(,,5)
datumi <- c()
datumi[1] <- as.character(as.Date("2012-07-24", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
spr[1,2] <- 0
spr[1,5] <- 0
for(j in 1:nrow(d)){
    if(d[j,4] == TRUE){
        spr <- rbind(spr,NA)
        datumi[l] <- if(j < nrow(d)){
            as.character(as.Date(d[{j+1},1], format = "%Y-%m-%d"))  
            } else {
            as.character(as.Date("2014-01-15", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
            }
        spr[l,1] <- difftime(datumi[l],datumi[l-1],units="days")  
        if(spr[l,1] == 0){
            spr[l,1] <- 1
        }
        spr[l,2] <- d[j,5] - spr[{l-1},5] 
        spr[l,3] <- spr[l,2] / spr[l,1]  
        spr[l,4] <- as.numeric(as.character(d[j,2]))  
        spr[l,5] <- d[j,5]
        l = l+1
    } 

datumi <- as.Date(datumi)
```

And then

```
days <- seq(from=as.Date("2012-07-24"), to=as.Date("2014-01-15"),by='days')


freq <- c()
  for(j in i:length(days)){
    for(k in 2:length(datumi)){
        if({datumi[k-1] <= days[j]} && {days[j] < datumi[k]}){
            freq[j] <- spr[k,3]
        }
    }
}
```

I get a vector of frequencies in variable 'freq'. The result in 'datumi' is now correct:

> datumi
>   [1] "2012-07-24" "2012-09-27" "2012-12-11" "2013-02-18" "2013-02-27"
>   [6] "2013-04-01"

So it seems that somehow the values (all but the first one) in variable 'datumi' get erased when I run it in an if loop but I cannot see why this happens only if I run both parts of the code together (1st case) and not if I run them one after another (second case).

Does anyone have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I think you have a subscript outside the length of a vector in one of the `if` statements. It is impossible to understand the way it's written, but check your subscripts are always between 1 and the length of each vector.

Comment: Can you provide us with the matrix `d` so that we can execute the above code? It is difficult to see what might be wrong without a reproducable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your combined code, in your first iteration, your variable `datumi` has length 1, which you can see by putting `print(datumi)` somewhere before the end of the first part of the code. Your second loop, however, starts from 2 and goes to 1 then. See the part `for(k in 2:length(datumi)){`. This says: for `k` in `2 then 1`, do `if({datumi[k-1] <= days[j]} && ...`. Hence, in the first iteration, `datum[2-1]` is accessed, and in the second iteration, `datumi[0]` is accessed, which does not exist.

On the other hand, when you execute the codes separately, the first part of your code returns `datumi` as a vector of length 6, and `k` will not assume the value `1` but go from 2 to 3 to ... to 6. This is why the second part of your code works when you execute them separately.

As a sidenote, please answer to comments asking you to provide additional information. We get notified about responses, but not about your edits that respond to our comments.

Comment: Thank you vey much for your answer! I've been looking for the solution for hours yesterday and now I found it with your help (and I have to admit that I feel a bit stupid) - I simply had to put an additional '}' on the before-last row on the first part of the code. This happened because I had another for loop and I forgot to end that one. Well I'm guessing lack of experience plus the fact that RStudio doesn't work on my computer and I have to do everything manually is at fault.